# Is it possible to remove/cancel a notification after the user sees it?

Tags: android

I am currently making an application that uses Notifications.

I was able to display the notifications, and remove them from the notification list when the user taps them. However, I would also like my notifications to disappear if the user sees them but does not act on them.

For instance, the user displays the notification list, then taps on a notification that is not mine, or just closes the notification list. During those cases, I am trying to make my notifications get canceled and not displayed the next time the user displays the notification list even if he did not do anything to my notification.

Is this possible?

Thanks! :D

(edit: if you are wondering why I thought of this, a very simplified explanation would be: think of the notification as a toast instead; a toast that has a longer existence, and makes sure that the user actually saw it before disappearing.)

Comment: Even if it is possible, it seems like a bad idea. I say leave it to the user to decide whether they want to remove them or not.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy, there is a **cancel method** for notifications:

```
public void cancel (int id)
```

Cancel a previously shown notification. If it's transient, the view will be hidden. If it's persistent, it will be removed from the status bar.

```
public void cancel (String tag, int id)
```

Cancel a previously shown notification. If it's transient, the view will be hidden. If it's persistent, it will be removed from the status bar.

```
public void cancelAll ()
```

Cancel all previously shown notifications. See cancel(int) for the detailed behavior.

**Details are here:**
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel(int)

**Update**

If you want to cancel your notification when user sees that notification, there is a flag for that, FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL:

```
Notification notification1 = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "test",
    System.currentTimeMillis());
notification1.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Comment: But what will be the trigger for me to call those methods? I guess my question is: How will I know that the user has seen my notification so that I can cancel it?

Comment: If you want to auto cancel your notifications, there is a flag for this. I've updated my answer, see that.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL cancels the notification after the user has tapped it. I also thought that it would "auto cancel" my notification, but after using it, it is not the kind of "auto" I am still looking for... (Though, I think I will not push through with my idea..)

Comment: I've looked but I couldn't find an event triggered when notification window is opened. One another idea is creating a background service and look for a suitable event for deciding if user saw your notification.

Answer (score 0):

you may remove a notification by providing its id to the cancel method:

```
((NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).cancel(your_notification);
```

however, i wouldn't recommend you to do it as it may confuse the user

Comment: "i wouldn't recommend you to do it as it may confuse the user" -> thanks, I will consider this.. :)